# When are the tensor product and the cartesian product of rings isomorphic?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, tensor-products, direct-sum, direct-product

Let's say I'm interested in (commutative) unital rings, and I assume homomorphisms to preserve the unit. Are there interesting rings R and S such that $$R\otimes_\mathbb{Z}S\cong R\oplus S$$ holds? I know that $$R=S=0$$ works, but I'd be interested in seeing other examples or possibly proofs of those being impossible.

Comment: A nice example over a base other than $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Roland: the first isomorphism doesn't hold, which you can check by reducing both sides $\bmod 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example is $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $S = \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$, the infinite product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Clearly $S\times S\cong S$. Is it clear that $S\otimes_\mathbb{Z}S\cong S$?

Comment: @JeremyRickard: It's not obvious to me whether that would be an isomorphism or not (my instincts say not), which is why I went for an $R \neq S$ example.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I misread your answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$\mathbb{F}_{p^2}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{F}_{p^2}\cong\mathbb{F}_{p^2}\times\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$$

(Pretty much the same as the example over $\mathbb{R}$ that Qiaochu gave in his comment.)